# Wants to navigate to particular screen when tap on push notification when flutter app is close/terminated

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, navigation

Below is the code for firebase push notification.Here I have used getInitialMessage() method to navigate on particular page when tapped on push notification but whenever I run the project with _handleMessage(message!) method in getInitialMessage() method project doesn't get executed and gets stuck on splash screen. Is there any other way to navigate to particular screen when tapped on push notification when app is closed/terminated. It's working fine when app is in background state.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/models/core/invoice_model.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/routes/router.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/screens/invoices_screens/invoices_screen.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/screens/starting_screens/landing_Screen.dart';

import '../../main.dart';
import '../../models/helper/service_locator.dart';

class FirebaseInitialization {
  FirebaseInitialization._privateConstructor();

  String? fcmToken;

  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static FirebaseInitialization sharedInstance =
      FirebaseInitialization._privateConstructor();

  //Notification Handle
  // void navigate() {

  // }

  void registerNotification() async {
   

    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        // firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
      } else {
        var val = await Permission.notification.isDenied;
        if (val) {}
      }

      var apnsToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
      fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      String tkn = fcmToken.toString();
      // String deviceToken =
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('theToken', tkn);

      log(fcmToken.toString());
      print('device token,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, $fcmToken');
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
     
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
        (RemoteMessage message) async {
          final data = message.data;
          print('onMessage:******************* ${data['Inv_id']}');
          showNotification(message.data, message.notification);

          return;
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print(error);
        },
       
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
       _handleMessage(message!);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      _handleMessage(message);
    });
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings();
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );
  }



  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data != null || message.data["entityid"] != null) {
      bool checkid = true;
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setBool('checkId', checkid);

      String entityid = message.data['entityid'];
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('entityid', entityid);

      if (message.data['module'] == 'Invoices' &&
          message.data['target'] != null) {
        String targetid = message.data['target'];
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('targetid', targetid);
        bool checkid = true;

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(upcomingDetails);
      } else if (message.data['module'] == 'Invoices' &&
          message.data['entityid'] != null &&
          message.data['target'] == null) {
        String entityid = message.data['entityid'];

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(landing);

        var targetid = null;
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('targetid', targetid);
      }

    
      else if (message.data['module'] == 'Payments') {
        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(totalPayment);
      } else if (message.data['module'] == 'KYC' &&
          message.data['entityid'] != null) {
        String entityid = message.data['entityid'];

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('companyId', entityid);

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(kycVerification);
      } else if (message.data['module'] == 'Entities') {
        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(InvoiceScreen);
      }
    }
  }

  void showNotification(
      Map<String, dynamic> data, RemoteNotification? remoteNotification) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'com.transport.trnasportplus',
      'Transport plus',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        DarwinNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(
          0,
          remoteNotification?.title ?? "",
          remoteNotification?.body ?? '',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: null,
        )
        .then((value) {});
  }
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
 

  print("Handling a background message");
}
```